# Why the Linux command CP behave differently in CLI and in script?

Tags: linux, bash, cp

I want to copy a bunch of Verilog/systemverilog sources, so I use CP with wildcard expression:

```
cp <some_dir>/*.{v,sv,svh} .
```

It works. But when I put it to a script with exactly the same line, the CP command fails with the log:

```
cp: cannot stat `../../mytest/spiTest/*.{v,sv,svh}': No such file or directory
```

How is that happening?

PS: I use bash as the shell.

---

And here is my script:

```
#!/bin/bash
rdir=../../mytest/spiTest
f1="$rdir/bench.lst"
f2="$rdir/cphex" #the script to copy rom data
f3="$rdir/make*" #makefile scripts
f4="$rdir/*.hex" #rom files
f5="$rdir/*.{v,sv,svh}" #testbench files
echo 'Copying files...'
cp $f1 $f2 $f3 $f4 .
cp $f5 .
```

---

I do changed the first line to

```
#!/bin/bash -vx
```

and run this script again, and I get:

```
#!/bin/bash -vx

rdir=../../mytest/spiTest
+ rdir=../../mytest/spiTest
f1="$rdir/bench.lst"
+ f1=../../mytest/spiTest/bench.lst
f2="$rdir/cphex" #the script to copy rom data
+ f2=../../mytest/spiTest/cphex
f3="$rdir/make*" #makefile scripts
+ f3='../../mytest/spiTest/make*'
f4="$rdir/*.hex" #rom files
+ f4='../../mytest/spiTest/*.hex'
f5="$rdir/*.{v,sv,svh}" #testbench files
+ f5='../../mytest/spiTest/*.{v,sv,svh}'

echo 'Copying files...'
+ echo 'Copying files...'
Copying files...
cp $f1 $f2 $f3 $f4 .
+ cp ../../mytest/spiTest/bench.lst ../../mytest/spiTest/cphex ../../mytest/spiTest/makefile ../../mytest/spiTest/makefile.defines ../../mytest/spiTest/rom.hex ../../mytest/spiTest/rom_if.hex .
cp $f5 .
+ cp '../../mytest/spiTest/*.{v,sv,svh}' .
cp: cannot stat `../../mytest/spiTest/*.{v,sv,svh}': No such file or directory
```

Comment: Put `#!/bin/bash -vx` as the first line of your shell to debug it.

Comment: Are you sure you execute the script from the same directory as the cp command you tried?

Answer (score 5):

Check the first line of the script. It probably reads:

```
#!/bin/sh
```

which switches the shell from BASH to Bourne Shell. Use

```
#!/bin/bash
```

instead.

**[EDIT]** You're running into problems with expansion. BASH has a certain order in which it expands patterns and variables. That means:

```
f5="$rdir/*.{v,sv,svh}" #testbench files
```

is quoted, so no file name expansion happens at this time. Only the variable `$rdir` is expanded. When

```
cp $f5 .
```

is executed, BASH first looks for file names to expand and there are none. Then it expands variables (`f5`) and then calls `cp` with two arguments: `../../mytest/spiTest/*.{v,sv,svh}` and `.`. Since `cp` expects the shell to have performed the file name expansion already, you get an error.

To fix this, you have to use arrays:

```
f5=($rdir/*.{v,sv,svh})
```

This replaces the variable and then expands the file names and puts everything into the array `f5`. You can then call `cp` with this array while preserving whitespaces:

```
cp "${f5[@]}" .
```

Every single character here is important. `[@]` tells BASH to expand the whole array here. The quotes say: Preserve whitespace. `{}` is necessary to tell BASH that `[@]` is part of the variable "name" to expand.

Comment: I'm not sure what kinds of expansions `ksh` supports.

Comment: Great, sir! It works, thanks a lot!!
Yet I have another problem. My current source directory does not contain any .svh file, so the script successfully copied all .v and .sv files but still got   a `cp: cannot stat \`../../mytest/spiTest/*.svh': No such file or directory` warning. How can I fix this one?

Comment: What does `"${f5[@]}"` expand to, specifically is there an `../../mytest/spiTest/*.svh` item at the end?

Answer (score 4):

Here's the problem: the order of substitutions. Bash performs brace expansion *before* variable expansion. In the line `cp $f5 .`, bash will do:

1. brace expansion: n/a

   - this is the key point: the variable contains a brace expression, but the shell does **not** see it now when it needs to.
2. tilde expansion: n/a
3. parameter expansion: yes -- `cp ../../mytest/spiTest/*.{v,sv,svh} .`
4. command substitution: n/a
5. arithmetic expansion: n/a
6. process substitution: n/a
7. word splitting: n/a
8. filename expansion: yes, bash looks for files in that directory ending with the string
   `.{v,sv,svh}`. It finds none, `nullglob` is not set, thus the pattern is not removed from the command
9. quote removal: n/a

Now the command is executed and fails with the error you see.

https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Shell-Expansions

Solutions:

1. use Aaron's idea of an array
2. (not recommended) force a 2nd round of expansions: `eval cp $f5 .`

Answer (score 1):

The line

```
 f5="$rdir/*.{v,sv,svh}" #testbench files
```

is probably wrong. First, avoid comments at end of line, they should be (at least for readability) in a separate line. Then, avoid using globbing in variable assignment. So remove that line, and code later (that is, replace the old `cp $f5 .` line with)

```
 cp "$rdir"/*.{v,sv,svh} .
```

BTW, I would test that `"$rdir"` is indeed a directory with

```
 if [ ! -d "$rdir" ] ; then
    echo invalid directory $rdir > /dev/stderr
    exit 1
 fi
```

You should read the [Advanced Bash Scripting Guide](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/)

Comment: Couple of points: nothing wrong with comments at end of line; `(exit 1)` exits the subshell, not the script.